# How do I run a command when opening cmd.exe with shortcut?

Tags: windows, command-line

I'd like to change the encoding of the command prompt when being opened rather than typing the command at the start of my session each time.

Below is the command I enter each time the command prompt starts now:

```
chcp 1252
```

How can I have this command run automatically when opening with the shortcut?

Comment: [Automatically executing commands when a command-prompt is opened](https://superuser.com/q/302194/241386)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the target box of your shortcut, use

```
cmd /K "chcp 1252"
```

This should run your program and leave the cmd window up when complete

Answer (score 9):

Per the [docs on cmd.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd),

The registry keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun\REG_SZ 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun REG_EXPAND_SZ
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Nice, this works for every cmd.exe, not just a particular shortcut.

Comment: To be clear, that means: find or make a key named Command Processor as specified, then in the right hand pane find AutoRun. If AutoRun is not there, right-click Command PRocessor and add an Expandable String Value named AutoRun, with a value of whatever you want run every time (e.g. chcp 1252).