# How to get Windows Command prompt to display time?

Tags: windows, command-line

I would like my command prompt (not powershell, just command prompt) to show the time, something like this:

`14:02>`

Is there a way to do this?  Basically, I leave things running from the prompt, and it would be nice to see what time I executed various commands.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
prompt $t$g
```

And see http://ss64.com/nt/prompt.html for a complete list

Comment: prompt $T$H$H$H$G gives me exactly what I want

Comment: `prompt $T$H$H$H$S$P$G` includes time & path

Comment: This is great combined with automatically running this when you open cmd: http://superuser.com/a/54923

Answer (score 22):

#### Attempt 1

Using `prompt $t$g` (as in the currently accepted answer) results in a prompt as in this example:

**`14:32:46,28>`**

#### Attempt 2

Using `prompt $P - $T$H$H$H$G` (as in the previously posted answer) results in a prompt like in this example:

**`C:\Users\Pierre.Vriens - 14:32:46>`**

#### Attempt 3

Using `prompt $T$H$H$H$H$H$H$G` (as mentioned also in a comment from OPer below the currently accepted answer) results in a prompt like in this example:

**`14:33>`**

So it looks like this attempt (= nr 3) is the correct answer ... (Credits: [Daniel Williams](https://superuser.com/users/75071/daniel-williams)), because:

- `$T` results in **`14:32:46,28`**.
- `$H$H$H$H$H$H` performs, 6 times, a backspace (i.e. removes the **`:46,28`** part of that).
- `$G`  adds **`>`** to it again.

Comment: Adding link to Microsoft documentation: [Windows Commands - prompt](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/prompt)

Answer (score 2):

use `time /t` to display the time
use `tzutil /g` to get the timezone info

Answer (score 1):

`prompt $P - $T$H$H$H$G` to have it more nicely maybe.

"`$P - $T$H$H$H$G`" is the format string for the prompt, and the `$` signs indicate characters with special meaning.

- `$P` - current path
- `$T` - current time - e.g. `HH:MM:SS.SS` (may vary with regional settings)
- `$H$H$H` - backspace three characters to remove the `.SS`
- `$G` - a "greater-than" sign at the end (`>`)

The end result looks something like: `C:\Users - 12:34:56>`

Comment: Could you explain?

Comment: go to this PC properties, Advanced settings, Environment, System variables, and add a variable PROMPT with the value I did mentioned so that you will have all future cmd prompts you will open with that prompt ;) Have fun.