# Make SSH run a command when a user connects?

Tags: windows-10, ssh, openssh

I'm running an openSSH server on my Windows 10 machine. Is there any way to automatically run a command when any user connects? I want a user that connects over ssh to have no choice but to run a specific command when they join.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically executing commands when a command-prompt is opened](https://superuser.com/questions/302194/automatically-executing-commands-when-a-command-prompt-is-opened)

Comment: That’s where I found the answer lol. I was hoping for something just for SSH, not any CMD prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using the registry.
I navigated to `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\` in regedit and created a key called `Command Processor`. I then created a new Expandable String Value called `AutoRun` in that key, and set it's value to a .cmd file. Now whenever a user connects to my SSH server it runs the commands in that file. Note that it will now run these commands whenever you run a batch file! I have it set to only run if it is in the home directory in the .cmd file.

I figured this out from this answer: [Automatically executing commands when a command-prompt is opened](https://superuser.com/questions/302194/automatically-executing-commands-when-a-command-prompt-is-opened/302553#302553)