# Hide "All rights reserved" message in CMD in Terminal

Tags: windows, windows-terminal

How can I stop this message from appearing every time I launch Windows Terminal with CMD:

[image]

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1706]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Comment: In PowerShell you have a profile, a script that is loaded and run each time you start PowerShell. Have you researched customizing your command prompt?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically executing commands when a command-prompt is opened](https://superuser.com/questions/302194/automatically-executing-commands-when-a-command-prompt-is-opened)

Comment: The second most up voted answer, not the selected answer, in the linked question answers your question I believe.

Answer (score 4):

go to
`windows terminal> settings> command prompt> command line`
and add /k in the end.

ex: `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /k`

Comment: I thought .. this is a stupid answer.. /k will simply keep the terminal open.  Tried it.  Nice answer! :) +1  Only difference is that I did it from the Run dialog.. but same thing.  I don't think you need to include the path.  `cmd.exe /k` alone should do the trick.

Comment: You can even adjust the prompt by adding e.g. `/k echo %USERNAME%@%COMPUTERNAME%.%USERDNSDOMAIN% in %CD%`

Answer (score 3):

This is sort-of possible, but there may be consequences. `cmd.exe` looks at two registry values (type *REG_SZ* or *REG_EXPAND_SZ*) when starting up:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`

Simply put `cls` in one of them and `cmd.exe` will automatically wipe the copyright notice, still leaving an empty line unfortunately.

Whether this could interfere with running batch files somehow, I don’t know. You’ll have to try. Fortunately, the change is easily reversible.

Answer (score 0):

> Hide "All rights reserved" message in CMD in Terminal

There is not a permanent solution for disabling the copyright but there are temporary solutions.

Microsoft owns the program (and others).  They are entitled to put their copyright on it.

If you look in Office products, the same copyright exists in the About section. Terminal is a simpler product than Office.

You can always clear the screen but the copyright will appear each time  you open terminal. So there are temporary ways.

I would be inclined also to respect copyrights in general.

Comment: You can always type `cls<enter>` :)

Comment: This kinda misunderstands the question, I think.

Comment: *"There is not much hope of that."* - Well, to be fair, Microsoft *does* allow you to disable the copyright notice in PowerShell via `powershell -nologo` or (for Core) `pwsh -nologo`, so it's certainly not unreasonable to hope for this with CMD.  It's just unlikely that Microsoft is going to go back and modify the legacy CMD to add that, at this point in time.