# How do I open cmd with multiple startup parameters (I mean execute two commands when startup)?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I am using listary as quick launch tool . I want to start cmd at some place and enter a python virtualenv, which need extra command `activate py3`.

I tried

```
cmd.exe /K cd /d "{query}" & "activate py3"
```

Here, `{query}` is the dir path.
But it doesn't work. What is the correct way ?

Comment: try putting a space in front of "activate"  ... `cmd.exe /K cd /d "{query}" & " activate py3"`

Comment: [How do I run a command when opening cmd.exe with shortcut?](https://superuser.com/q/54919/241386), [Automatically executing commands when a command-prompt is opened](https://superuser.com/q/302194/241386)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved,

```
cmd.exe /K "cd /d {query} && activate py3"
```

The form is:

```
cmd.exe /K "command1 && command2"
```

Comment: Please consider adding a bit of explanation as to why this solution works.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to Question has already been answered, I'll just explain it a bit further. In Windows Command Line, We can execute multiple commands in just a single line

Using `'&' (Ampersand)` OR `'&&' (Double Ampersand)`

Using Single Ampersand `&` causes Sequential Execution ie. Commands run in the sequence they are entered. There is no condition checking in it. There may be a case when second command can execute successfully Only If the first command is executed successfully.

That introduces Double Ampersand `&&` . This operator is kind of conditional operator and performs an Error Checking ie. Second command will execute only if the first command is executed successfully.

Example :

> $ cd Docs & dir

First `cd Docs` will run & regardless of whether it was successful or not, second command `dir` will run.

1. `If Docs folder exist` then It will change the directory & then list contents of Docs using `dir` command.
2. However `If Docs folder doesn't exist` then It will give an error, but still `dir` will run to list the contents of current directory.

> $ cd Docs && dir

Here, `dir` command will run only when current Directory is changed to Docs and that will happen `only when Docs exist`. So, you can interpret the command like - " If folder Docs exists, change the current directory and then list it's contents. "

This is very much useful in the Batch Programming and sometimes at Command-Line too.